# Regex to find multiple matches in between two strings

Tags: c#, regex, string

Here is a link to the string I am trying to do regex from: http://pastebin.com/raw/TRKbqGxs

Yes, I know regex is not the best for parsing HTML, but I want to use it in this project. I don't want to use HTML Ability Pack at this moment.

My main interest are lines like these:

`data-screen-name="thanhbach195" data-name="Mai Thanh Bách" data-protected="false">`

`data-screen-name="zeref980" data-name="Yan Naung Htet" data-protected="false">`

I want to export the data between following chunks of text `data-screen-name="` and `" data-name=`.

Basically, in this case `thanhbach195` and `zeref980`.

I tried the following regex: `string reg = "data-screen-name=\"(.*)\" data-name=\"";`

But I didn't get the answer of the multiple matches for some reason. In fact, it doesn't seem to be extracting the string I want at all.

I would appreciate if someone can help me write a correct regex to extract all matches between those 2 strings in the string that I uploaded above.

```
private List<string> getUsers(string str)
        {
            List<string> users = new List<string>();
            string reg = "data-screen-name=\"(.*)\" data-name=\"";
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(str, reg);
            foreach(Match m in mc)
            {
                users.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            return users;
        }
```

This code returns the same match every time (first one I believe it is).

Comment: You should be using Html Agility Pack for this.  But you already know that.

Comment: But It works fine. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/PN5bJ.png). How are you accessing the value of the group? Are there more than one matches in your html?

Comment: Yes @MaximilianGerhardt there are more than 1 matches, which is my problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree but I'd like to use regex for this software I'm writing right now. Html Agility Pack definitely makes it a lot easier though.

Comment: `foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(inputHTML, reg)) { Console.WriteLine( m.Groups[1].Value); }`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I did. Suppose I have to use groups, how would I access all the groups of all matches? Right now, I am just getting the same output every time. I'll update my first post with an example.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt That is what I've been doing pretty much and I keep getting the same output every time.

Comment: Code looks good, go set a breakpoint on the `Add()` function and debug it. Take a look at what entries the list has and how the list is then further processed.

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianGerhardt for the time. I got it working! :)

Comment: I must add again and again: do not use dot matching patterns to parse delimited text. Use negated character classes, sometimes with alternations.

Comment: Without using groups you may also try this one `/[^"]+?(?="\s*data-name=")/g`

Comment: And it works - http://ideone.com/wTJpM5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Disclaimer

You should really use an HTML parsing engine as there are many obscure edge cases that regex can't easily accommodate. But I'm not your mom, so I'm not going to tell you how to live your life.

Since it appears that you have some control over your source text, you'll probably be able to completely avoid the obscure edge cases.

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- find all the `div` tags
- ensure each `div` tag found contains a `class="user-actions` with or without the quote
- captures the values for `data-screen-name`, `data-name`, and `data-protected` into their own capture groups
- allows attribute/value sets to appear in any order
- allows the quotes around value to be optional, so you can use single quotes, double quotes, or no quotes
- scrubs quotes from the values, so you get the raw value
- avoids a lot of the messy edge cases the regex police cry about when matching HTML

**The Regex**

`<div\b(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?class=['"]?user-actions)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?data-screen-name=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?data-name=(['"]?)(.*?)\3(?:\s|>))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?data-protected=(['"]?)(.*?)\5(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='(?:[^']|\\')*'|="(?:[^"]|\\")*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*\s*>`

I recommend using the case insensitive flag.

## Examples

**Excerpt From Source Text**

A tiny portion of your sample text

```
<div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting protected" data-user-id="726459723365502976"
data-screen-name="Just__Kidding__" data-name="Chaw Chin Fong" data-protected="true">
```

**Live Example**

Shows just a larger portion of your overall file because the online tool gets bogged down with huge strings of text.

https://regex101.com/r/bY1kH8/1

**Capture Groups**

- Group 0 gets the entire opening div tag
- Group 1 gets is assigned the quote if there was one around the `data-screen-name` value
- Group 2 get the `data-screen-name` value, not including any quotes
- Group 3 gets is assigned the quote if there was one around the `data-name` value
- Group 4 get the `data-name` value, not including any quotes
- Group 5 gets is assigned the quote if there was one around the `data-protected` value
- Group 6 get the `data-protected` value, not including any quotes

**Sample Matches**

These were taken from your source text using the proposed regular expression.

```
[0][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="2582252852"
        data-screen-name="w33haa" data-name="Aliwi Omar" data-protected="false">
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = w33haa
[0][3] = "
[0][4] = Aliwi Omar
[0][5] = "
[0][6] = false

[1][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="1680222842"
        data-screen-name="Jamjomon" data-name="Jamchu :3" data-protected="false">
[1][1] = "
[1][2] = Jamjomon
[1][3] = "
[1][4] = Jamchu :3
[1][5] = "
[1][6] = false

[2][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="1523823648"
        data-screen-name="dimakoza4enko" data-name="Дима Козаченко" data-protected="false">
[2][1] = "
[2][2] = dimakoza4enko
[2][3] = "
[2][4] = Дима Козаченко
[2][5] = "
[2][6] = false

[3][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="1522238240"
        data-screen-name="alupulipulipala" data-name="Wahid Arefin" data-protected="false">
[3][1] = "
[3][2] = alupulipulipala
[3][3] = "
[3][4] = Wahid Arefin
[3][5] = "
[3][6] = false

[4][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="4804204573"
        data-screen-name="thanhbach195" data-name="Mai Thanh Bách" data-protected="false">
[4][1] = "
[4][2] = thanhbach195
[4][3] = "
[4][4] = Mai Thanh Bách
[4][5] = "
[4][6] = false

[5][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="726465523223908353"
        data-screen-name="zeref980" data-name="Yan Naung Htet" data-protected="false">
[5][1] = "
[5][2] = zeref980
[5][3] = "
[5][4] = Yan Naung Htet
[5][5] = "
[5][6] = false

[6][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting protected" data-user-id="726459723365502976"
        data-screen-name="Just__Kidding__" data-name="Chaw Chin Fong" data-protected="true">
[6][1] = "
[6][2] = Just__Kidding__
[6][3] = "
[6][4] = Chaw Chin Fong
[6][5] = "
[6][6] = true

[7][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="713605605638938624"
        data-screen-name="Fruitcentre" data-name="Fruit &amp; Veg Centre" data-protected="false">
[7][1] = "
[7][2] = Fruitcentre
[7][3] = "
[7][4] = Fruit &amp; Veg Centre
[7][5] = "
[7][6] = false

[8][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting protected" data-user-id="555968644"
        data-screen-name="aeronhalecastle" data-name="Eywon ツ" data-protected="true">
[8][1] = "
[8][2] = aeronhalecastle
[8][3] = "
[8][4] = Eywon ツ
[8][5] = "
[8][6] = true

[9][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="2845398050"
        data-screen-name="Deheyb" data-name="4k Scrub✌️" data-protected="false">
[9][1] = "
[9][2] = Deheyb
[9][3] = "
[9][4] = 4k Scrub✌️
[9][5] = "
[9][6] = false

[10][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="721815663216566272"
        data-screen-name="Ribbon2712" data-name="Даниил Демидов" data-protected="false">
[10][1] = "
[10][2] = Ribbon2712
[10][3] = "
[10][4] = Даниил Демидов
[10][5] = "
[10][6] = false

[11][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="3248438456"
        data-screen-name="zayarmgmg95" data-name="Zayar Mg" data-protected="false">
[11][1] = "
[11][2] = zayarmgmg95
[11][3] = "
[11][4] = Zayar Mg
[11][5] = "
[11][6] = false

[12][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="726440286063198208"
        data-screen-name="Ninderpy" data-name="Derpy" data-protected="false">
[12][1] = "
[12][2] = Ninderpy
[12][3] = "
[12][4] = Derpy
[12][5] = "
[12][6] = false

[13][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="423763655"
        data-screen-name="ImJoehuff" data-name="JoeyT" data-protected="false">
[13][1] = "
[13][2] = ImJoehuff
[13][3] = "
[13][4] = JoeyT
[13][5] = "
[13][6] = false

[14][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="726441786839703556"
        data-screen-name="zxmir_" data-name="Zxmir_" data-protected="false">
[14][1] = "
[14][2] = zxmir_
[14][3] = "
[14][4] = Zxmir_
[14][5] = "
[14][6] = false

[15][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="726440845713367041"
        data-screen-name="hienlequang" data-name="Hiền Lê Quang" data-protected="false">
[15][1] = "
[15][2] = hienlequang
[15][3] = "
[15][4] = Hiền Lê Quang
[15][5] = "
[15][6] = false

[16][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="3032113115"
        data-screen-name="Najer14" data-name="Jan" data-protected="false">
[16][1] = "
[16][2] = Najer14
[16][3] = "
[16][4] = Jan
[16][5] = "
[16][6] = false

[17][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="4762819022"
        data-screen-name="7forOne" data-name="Abiel" data-protected="false">
[17][1] = "
[17][2] = 7forOne
[17][3] = "
[17][4] = Abiel
[17][5] = "
[17][6] = false

[18][0] = <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="717061680799330306"
        data-screen-name="Th3uN1qu31" data-name="Th3_uN1Qu3" data-protected="false">
[18][1] = "
[18][2] = Th3uN1qu31
[18][3] = "
[18][4] = Th3_uN1Qu3
[18][5] = "
[18][6] = false
```

## Explained

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <div                     '<div'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    class=                   'class='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    user-actions             'user-actions'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    data-screen-name=        'data-screen-name='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    data-name=               'data-name='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \3                       what was matched by capture \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    data-protected=          'data-protected='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \5                       what was matched by capture \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']                     any character except: '''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]                     any character except: '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a non-greedy named regular expression of that terminates at the next double quote instead of a greedy match

```
string reg = "data-screen-name=\"(?<dataScreenName>[^\"]+)\" data-name=\"(?<dataName>[^\"]+\"";
```

this will allow you to use

```
foreach(Match m in mc)
{
    users.Add(m.Groups["dataScreenName"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Apparently, I missed something else. The regex was not the problem, as it works with the same I posted in the question.